# How to choose dates after a certain year in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In short, when I do the following SQL command:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) AS year FROM news_stories
```

I get a big list of years from 2008-2014.

But if I do

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) AS year FROM news_stories WHERE year > 2010
```

I get an empty result.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Output columns are visible in the `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` clause, because those are applied *after* evaluating expressions in the `SELECT` clause. They are **not visible** in the **`WHERE`** or `HAVING` clause. So you cannot reference the *output* column name `year`. You would have to repeat the expression based on *input* columns. Obviously, there is an input column of the same name, or you would get an exception. Details:

- [How to re-use result for SELECT, WHERE and ORDER BY clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074546/how-to-re-use-result-for-select-where-and-order-by-clauses/14075977#14075977)

For your query to be **fast**, you should rather use a **[sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable)** predicate:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) AS year
FROM   news_stories
WHERE  pub_date >= '2010-1-1'::date;
```

This is generally faster, because Postgres can compare values in the `pub_date` to the given value directly, without extracting the year from every row first.
More importantly, a plain index on `pub_date` can be used this way - if Postgres expects that route to be faster (index-only scan or selective enough).

Comment: So the tl;dr I took from that is "WHERE  pub_date >= '2010-1-1'::date" is faster than "WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) > 2010"?  I just did some AB speed testing and saw no change (the script takes 3-5 seconds to run in either case)… but if you say it's better to go the sargable method, I'm good with that. :-)  Thanks!

Comment: @DanGoodspeed: You'll see a big difference with an index on `pub_date` in place when you select a small part of the table or if pg can use an index-only scan ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244026/optimize-groupwise-maximum-query/24377356#24377356)). When large parts of the table have to be read, pg will use a sequential scan and you'll hardly see a difference. Either way, 3-5 sec seems *very* long. Is your table huge? How do you measure? What's your version of pg? I would use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to test. You don't want to include network overhead in your tests.

Comment: It was a very unscientific test.  It's a perl script which does a few database calls run through the web (this being one of them), and I just timed the page-load.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You cannot use the`alias name`in where clause. The `WHERE clause` is processed before the `SELECT clause(*)`. Since you have Column named `Year` you didn't get a Error.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) AS year 
FROM news_stories 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) > 2010
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought one of the main purposes of AS was to be able to shorten some of these SQL statements like how I wrote it.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed ALIASES can be used to create a **temporary** name for columns or tables. If you want use the alias name in `where Clause` then check Gordan answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a column named `year` in the database, because otherwise the SQL would return an error.  YOu cannot use an alias in the `select` or `where` clause where it is defined.

Either use a subquery or repeat the expression:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) AS year
FROM news_stories
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) > 2010;
```

Or as a subquery:

```
select *
from (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM pub_date) AS year
      FROM news_stories
     ) n
where year > 2010;
```