# Fetch similar rows based on tag intersection

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Given a table with 2 cols, id (bigserial) and tags (varchar(64)[])

```
id|tags
--------
1 |a,b,c
2 |a,c
3 |d,e
```

what would an optimal query be that would fetch rows based on tag intersection count (ic)?

So searching for a,b,c would return

```
id|ic
-----
1 |3
2 |2
3 |0
```

Comment: I don't understand how the intersection count is defined.  Can you explain it in more formal terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, count(tag = ANY ('{a,b,c}') OR NULL) AS ic
FROM   tbl t
     , unnest(tags) x(tag)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

That's an [implicit `JOIN LATERAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html). Rows with empty or NULL arrays are excluded. To *include* those, use:

```
LEFT JOIN unnest(tags) x(tag) ON TRUE
```

OTOH, if you are only interested in rows with at least one match you could pre-select with the [overlap array operator **`&&`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) for better performance:

```
SELECT t.id, count(tag = ANY ('{a,b,c}') OR NULL) AS ic
FROM  (SELECT * tbl WHERE tags && '{a,b,c}') t
     , unnest(tags) x(tag)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`&&` can be supported with a GIN index, which would make the difference for a big table.

More about the counting technique:

- [Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)

Comment: You're amazing Erwin! Thank you! One more question if you don't mind -- what's x(tag) doing? And why can't I reference ic anywhere else in the query, say for filtering purposes with a "where ic > 0"

Comment: @rebnoob: `unnest(tags) x(tag)` is short for `unnest(tags) AS x(tag)`, where `x` is a table alias and `tag` is a column alias. You could also write `unnest(tags) tag`, then `tag` would serve as both table *and* column alias. As for why you can't reference `ic` in the `WHERE` clause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074546/how-to-re-use-result-for-select-where-and-order-by-clauses/14075977#14075977 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848930/group-by-case-statement/19849537#19849537

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, IF(('a' = ANY(tags)),1,0) + IF(('b' = ANY(tags)),1,0) + IF(('c' = ANY(tags)),1,0) AS ic
FROM mytable
```

Comment: `tags` is an array, not a string.  Moreover, you're assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are the only tags.

Comment: There is no `IF` in Postgres (or standard) SQL. That's a MySQL oddity. Use `CASE` instead.