# PostgreSql query to sort data by given latitude longitude value

Tags: postgresql, latitude-longitude

Query that sorts rows as per given latitude longitude. Sort by near to far location

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort by proximity after getting distance using pythagoras - postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477571/sort-by-proximity-after-getting-distance-using-pythagoras-postgresql)

Comment: Don't use Pythagoras formula on lat-longs, it is plain **wrong** as a degree of latitude doesn't have the same ground length, in meters, as a degree of longitude (@RichardHansell, @SQLpro). Instead you can Postgis and the operator `<->` on geographies (NOT on lat-long geometries), or you can compute the distance yourself using the haversine formula.

Answer (score 0):

From a point like A (lat = 3, long = 2), you can use ORDER BY like this :

```
ORDER BY SQRT(SQUARE((lat-latitude) + SQUARE((long-longitude))
```

But it would be much more smart if you use spatial functions like ST_Distance